# Saving float and double precision in C++ during cin/cout and scanf/printf

Tags: printf, scanf, cout, cin, floating-accuracy

I want to read floats and doubles from standart input and save its precision (exact the same digits after floating point) and be able to output (cout/printf) as it is. What the most convinient (and simplest way) to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Since float/double are not infinite precision, the only way to do this reliably is to read it in as a string and to maintain the original string along with the converted float/double.

Comment: It is impossible to do. The reason is obvious - in stdin/stdout floating point numbers are represented as decimal numbers (it is a requirement of standards). C or C++ standards do not specify internal representation of floating point numbers, therefore there cannot be possible to write a portable conversion from string to float/double and backwards. Even used de-facto standard representation of the numbers does not allow decimal to binary reversible conversions in general case. To illustrate: try to convert 1/3 into decimal notation and back, keeping precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
float f;
cin >> f;
cout << f;
```

Comment: But with double 12345.56789 the same aproach doesn't work.
    double d;
    cin >> d; 
    cout << d;

Answer (score 0):

Use `setprecision`.

Here is the solution

```
cout<<setprecision(the precision you want to set here)<<variablename;
```

eg. If you want to set precision of the output to 5  for variable `var` use it like this:

```
cout<<setprecision(5)<<var;
```

`setprecision` is a manipulator. Learn more about manipulators [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).

It sets the decimal precision to be used to

format floating-point values on output operations. 
 Behaves as if member precision were called with n as argument on the
 stream on which it is inserted/extracted as a manipulator (it can be
 inserted/extracted on input streams or output streams).

This is a manipulator and is declared in header `<iomanip>`

Answer (score 0):

Since the input has an unknown precision, the simplest method is to read them as strings, not doubles/floats.

If you need the float value, a simple string to double conversion is needed.

Any other method will probably fail since you rely on imperfect conversion from string to float done by the standard library.

The latter can't distinguish between 0.4 and 0.40.